# Git How to cancel / view local changes which conflict with updates from Git?

Tags: git

I have current repo with changed files, but some of them are also changed in Git, so I want to update local repo with saving my new files and files without conflict.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

then try to stash your local changes first, then pull, then pop the stash.

```
git stash
git pull origin master
git stash pop
```

and anything that overwrite changes from remote will have conflicts, which you will have to resolve manually.

Comment: see if this works for you.